# Get digits before file extension using regex

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I want to extract two pieces of information from a list of filenames using regex.
The two numbers are always located just before the file extension and separated by a dash.
In the example filename below, I would aim for 10 and 11.
To get the digit just before the extension (so 11 in the example), I am using `\d+(?=.raw)` and it seems to work.
However, I struggle to get something similar for the number before (so 10 in this example).

```
D:\CDTFlatten02\20210730-HK-S-006-PLATE-flatten-sliced\20210730-HK-S-006-PLATE-flatten-10-11.raw\
```

The expression is to be used to create a new column in a pandas dataframe in the following way: `df['y'] = df['Filename'].apply(lambda x: re.findall('\d+(?=.raw)', x)[0])`

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts, could you please post samples of output also in your question, thank you.

Comment: Why not just use `/(\d+)\-(\d+)\.raw/g`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
data = {'Filename': ['something-1-2.csv','something-10-11.raw']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

pattern = r'(\d+)-(\d+(?=\..+$))'

df['y'] = df['Filename'].apply(lambda x: re.findall(pattern,x)[0])
print(df)

              Filename         y
0    something-1-2.csv    (1, 2)
1  something-10-11.raw  (10, 11)

# or if you want to split them in different cols immediately, try:
df[['y1','y2']] = df['Filename'].apply(lambda x: re.findall(pattern,x)[0]).tolist()
print(df)

              Filename  y1  y2
0    something-1-2.csv   1   2
1  something-10-11.raw  10  11
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to utilize `str.findall()` instead:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Filename': [r'D:\CDTFlatten02\20210730-HK-S-006-PLATE-flatten-sliced\20210730-HK-S-006-PLATE-flatten-10-11.raw\'']})
df['y'] = df['Filename'].str.findall(r'\d+(?=(?:-\d+)?\.[^.]+$)')

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                                          Filename         y
0  D:\CDTFlatten02\20210730-HK-S-006-PLATE-flatte...  [10, 11]
```

---

Pattern used:

```
\d+(?=(?:-\d+)?\.[^.]+$)
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/hyiZj0/1)

- `\d+` - 1+ Digits;
- `(?=` - Open positive lookahead;

  - `(?:-\d+)?` - Optional non-capture group to match hyphen and 1+ digits;
  - `\.[^.]+$` - Literal dot followed by 1+ non-dots and end-line anchor.

---

**EDIT**:

Or, if you must put these in seperate columns, we can use `str.extract()`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Filename': [r'D:\CDTFlatten02\20210730-HK-S-006-PLATE-flatten-sliced\20210730-HK-S-006-PLATE-flatten-10-11.raw\'']})
df[['y1','y2']] = df['Filename'].str.extract(r'(\d+)-(\d+)\.[^.]+$')

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                                            Filename  y1  y2
0  D:\CDTFlatten02\20210730-HK-S-006-PLATE-flatte...  10  11
```

Where the main difference in the pattern is that we got rid of the lookahead and instead used two capture groups to grab the numbers.